# Out of position meshes imported from FBX

Tags: mesh, .fbx, origin

As you can see from the picture, I'm having trouble importing a static fbx mesh from 3ds max into blender. I find out it's because linked meshes into 3ds Max. Is there a way to avoid this without unlinking those meshes into Max?

[image]